# Assign single task to multiple users in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

```
taskid     tasktitle     assigned to 

1          A             DEMO

2          B             TEST

3          C             DEMO,TEST
```

```php
$caccess= $user->authorise('core.admin');                       

if( !$caccess ) {
    $query->where('task.assignedto='.$user->id);
}
```

I placed the above code in `ListQuery` Function in model but only `task A` is coming for `DEMO USER`.

I need `TASK A` and `TASK C` For `DEMO USER` and `TASK B` and `TASK C` for `TEST USER`.
In the database , assigned field are stored like `demo,test` for `TASK C`.

How should I write the retrieval query?

Comment: I'm sorry but I dn't understand what the query. $user->id is going to give you the user id not a name.  Also if you really want to store that as comma separated values and not as separate records you are going to have to tell the query to look for substrings. Do you have a query that is working in phpmyadmin? If so write a query that matches that.  But really, store it as separate records, dn't store two import pieces of data that you want to query in the same field.

Comment: actually am assigning same task to two persons and am storing user id in database not names for reference i wrote names

Comment: Either way make two rows.